# Randomize Header Image to Sync With Post Link on Ghost.JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, handlebars.js, ghost-blog, ghost

I'm trying to have my header-image sync up with a click through link on Ghost.js. I've been able to generate a random link on each new page load, but am unsure how to have the header image that belongs to that link get pulled with it.

Is anyone familiar with ghost and understand how hbs would be used in the code below? Do I need to use hbs or can I use 'post.image' to sync image with 'post.url'

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get(
        ghost.url.api('posts', {limit: 'all'})
    ).done(onSuccess);
});

function onSuccess(data) {
    var $result = $('#featured');
    var sortedPosts = shuffleArray(data.posts);
    var displayPosts = sortedPosts.slice(0,1);
    $.each(displayPosts, function (i, post) {
        $result.append(
            '<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i><a href="http://www.enflight.design/' + post.url + '">' + post.title + '</a></li>'
        );
    });
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the `post.image` will be the cover image of the same post you are using for the post.url. So if you wanted to append an image and the link, just add the image source in with `post.image` and it should render just fine. Like this:

```
$result.append(
    '<img src=' + post.image + '>'
    '<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i><a href="http://www.enflight.design/' + post.url + '">' + post.title + '</a></li>'
);
```

Does that make sense? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi David, thank you! It definitely help point me in the right direction. Looks like the img src needed to be closed out and added to the li. '<img src='" + post.image + '"/>' +